# Can Conhost.exe be disabled?

Tags: windows-8.1

Is there anyway to disable conhost.exe.  During state testing for our students it keeps popping up and when it does it knocks the students out of the test.  Is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. `conhost.exe` is used to host console applications, and is automatically started by programs such as `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe`. If any program you're using requires a console host, then you *will* have `conhost.exe` in the background, otherwise the application won't work.

If you need to get rid of `conhost.exe`, then you need to close any applications which require a console host. (Usually, the parent process of `conhost.exe` in Windows 8. In Windows 7, the parent was always `csrss.exe`, a critical system process)